# Eclipse not working: Exec format error

Tags: gnome, 14.04, eclipse

I have installed Eclipse as following:

1 → Download `eclipse-standard-kepler-SR2-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz` to my 14.04

[image]

2 → Extracted it using the command,

```
sudo tar -xvf eclipse-standard-kepler-SR2-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz
```

3 → Moved eclipse to `/opt/` using command,

```
sudo mv eclipse /opt/
```

4 → Created Icon(64x64) for eclipse using GIMP Image Editor.

5 → Installed gnome-panel using,

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends gnome-panel
```

6 → And Create Application by using,

```
sudo gnome-desktop-item-edit /usr/share/applications/ --create-new
```

[image: img1]

7 → Select Icon,

[image: img3]

8 → Select eclipse application for comment,

[image]

9 → Finally enter command and click OK.

[image]

I have given everything required, and the application created and showing,

[image]

But when I open this application it's not working.

(Note: I have created another one, because first one not worked, and now both not working. That why picture showing two eclipse.)

When I tried to open it in terminal, I got

```
bash: /opt/eclipse/eclipse: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Please tell me where the problem may occur ?

Comment: BTW you downloaded Kepler but called it Juno in shortcut. It might take displeasure =)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you get

```
/opt/eclipse/eclipse: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

that usually means you use the wrong architecture. In this case you downloaded the 64bit version but should use the 32bit version of Eclipse.

Comment: thank you friend.. lately I found that.. when I came here to post.. I saw your post.. thanks again..

Comment: use linux `file` utility to check architecture of the file: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2902650/304285

Answer (score 1):

> when I tried to open in terminal, am getting  `bash: /opt/eclipse/eclipse: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

That means the file is damaged. Perhaps something went wrong while you did extraction. To ensure that it's not archive problem, follow [these instructions](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/downloads/verifyMD5.php):

1. Every download has an associated link "(md5)" to a *.md5 file containing its MD5 checksum. Download this file into the same directory as the appropriate `tar.gz` file.
2. Execute the command `md5sum -c <gzfilename>.md5`. The result `<gzfilename>: OK` is indicative of an intact download.

If the check succeeds, you have to remove Eclipse (`sudo rm -rf /opt/eclipse`) and repeat the steps you mentioned. If not, you have to redownload the file.

Comment: am getting the same error again..

Comment: Please run `ls -l /opt/eclipse/eclipse` and show the output.

Comment: the result is, `-rwxr-xr-x 1 messagebus users 73031 Jan 16 04:44 /opt/eclipse/eclipse`

Comment: I have fix the problem.. it was stupid, I download 64-bit instead of 32-bit... thank you so much

Comment: Ugh... I'm stupid too =) Please upvote the answer you accepted.

Comment: did for both answers...